# A question on choosing numbers to form geometric sequence

Tags: combinatorics

So the question states:

> In how many ways can you choose three numbers from $1,2,...,100$ to form a geometric sequence $k,{km \over n}, {km^2 \over n^2}$ such that $n \gt 1$,$m \gt n$,$n^2|k$ and $hcf(m,n)=1$.

I tried by first asserting that $km^2 \le 100n^2$,so if $n$ is chosen, the number of choosing $k$ is given by the function $$f(n)= \sum_{m \gt n,(m,n)=1} \big[{{100n^2} \over m^2}\big]$$
which disagrees with the solution provided which states $$f(n)= \sum_{m \gt n,(m,n)=1} \big[{{100} \over m^2}\big]$$

I feel a bit confused as to why $n$ disappeared, could someone help me please?

note:$[...]$ is the symbol for taking the largest integer value.

Comment: Perhaps I am misreading, but:  if we take n = 99 then m can only be 100, yes?  However, in that case $\left[ \frac{100}{100^2}\right]=0$ which would mean that there were no choices for k, which is plainly false.

Comment: @lulu, if $1\le k\le100$ and $n^2\mid k$ then I don't see how $n$ can be $99$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Ah, thank you!  I missed that constraint.  Thought I must be misreading.

Comment: May I note my paper on finding the number of length-3 geometric progressions from $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, http://www.austms.org.au/Gazette/2008/Jul08/TechPaperMyerson.pdf

Comment: @GerryMyerson But in that case, I think I agree with the stated solution:  if we write $k=Ln^2$ then we require that $k \frac {m^2}{n^2} = Lm^2 ≤ 100$.